# Two haskell questions im stuck on

Tags: haskell

Been working through some haskell questions, got stuck on these two, the answer is simple but my brain can't work it out.

Write a function which determines how many of its three arguments are equal (i.e. it returns either 0, 2 or 3).

```
howManyEqual :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
howManyEqual x y z
    | x == y && x == z && y == z = 3
    |
```

Write a function which returns how many of its three integer arguments are greater than their
average value.

```
howManyAboveAverage :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
howManyAboveAverage x y z
    | x > average(x y z) && y > average(x y z) && z > average(x y z) = 3
    where
    average a b c = ((a + b + c) / 3)
```

Could someone help me finish these please :)

thanks

Comment: Could you be more specific about what parts of the code you understand and what is confusing you?  Notice your function application of `average` is wrong - it should be written `average x y z`.

Comment: Just solving then in general, the code i out down is what i came up with so far but could and probs is quite wrong :/

Answer (score 2):

Edited as first solution was a bit of an overkill :)

First solution just uses plain guards:

```
howManyEqual :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
howManyEqual x y z
  | x == y && y == z = 3
  | x /= y && x /= z && y /= z = 0
  | otherwise = 2
```

Second solution uses some basic functions such as filter and length.

```
howManyAboveAverage :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
howManyAboveAverage x y z = length . filter (>average) $ [x,y,z]
  where average = (x + y + z) `div` 3
```

I don't think the integer division `div` is going to be a problem in this case. it truncates the decimal, but seeing as the inputs are integers anyways:
x > avg implies x > floor(avg) and
x <= avg implies x <= floor(avg)

Hope that works! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: average x y z = (x + y + z) / 3 **and** filter ((>average) . fromIntegral)

Comment: I think seeing as the arguments are only ints, doing it this way works  the same (i.e. yields the same results) without having to use fromIntegral (which would also be needed when calculating the average). The property mentioned in the second to last paragraph should hold in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

you better start thinking in lists, in the first task `maximum` and

```
import Data.List (group,sort)
```

are your friends

```
howManyEqual x y z = "length of longest group of equal things" - 1

howManyAboveAverage x y z = let xs = [x,y,z]
                                avg = undefined -- you can do that
                            in length $ "get all elements > average from" xs
```

in the second part a function named `filter` is helpful.

I know this is not valid haskell code, but it should help you solving that problem.

### EDIT:

then you have to write a bit more in the first case, in the second case - filter is in the standard library

```
howManyEqual :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
howManyEqual x y z
    | x == y && x == z = 3 
    | x == y && x /= z = 2
    | x    z && y    z = 2
    | x    y && y    z = 2
    | otherwise = 0
```

Comment: hey thanks for the reply, but we're not allowed to use imported stuff for these tasks

Comment: `length $ group [x,y,z]` is `3` even if x and z are equal

Comment: @Parallelist sort first

Comment: @eccstartup OK but that’s not what epsilonhalbe said

Comment: @Parallelist Data.List(group) will do this work `howManyEqual x y z = "length of longest group of equal things" - 1` if you sort it first.